# Multiple rows with multiple values ​with same [formControl]

Tags: angular, typescript, material-ui

my need is to create a table with editable fields, below the solution that I adopted.

**Ps.You are free to create a stackblitz, I've tried but I'm not able to**

The problem with this is that when I create a new row with other inputs, the drop-down menu that should be empty in the new row assumes the value of the last previously selected one (see GIF):

[**GIF**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIof3.gif)

**Component.html**

```
<mat-card class="container-card">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="table-container">
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" formArrayName="data" class="main-table">
          <!-- Row definitions -->
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

          <!-- Column definitions -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="descrizione">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descrizione </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index" [formGroupName]="index" class="base-table">
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <input matInput name="descrizione" (focus)="resetDescriptionFilter()" [formControl]="descFilter" formControlName="descrizione" class="table-input" [matAutocomplete]="autodescrizione">
                <mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="setDescValue(index,$event.option.value)" autoActiveFirstOption #autodescrizione="matAutocomplete">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let categoria of tempcategoryproduct" [value]="categoria">
                    {{categoria}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="codarticolo">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Cod. Articolo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index"  [formGroupName]="index" class="base-table">
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <input matInput name="codarticolo" [formControl]="codartFilter" formControlName="codarticolo" class="table-input">
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autodescrizione="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let categoria of tempcategoryproduct" [value]="categoria">
                  {{categoria}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-autocomplete>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="costo">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Costo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index"  [formGroupName]="index" class="base-table">
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill"  id="price-input">
                <input matInput name="costo" formControlName="costo" class="table-input">
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="qta">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Quantità </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index"  [formGroupName]="index" class="base-table">
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill"  id="price-input">
                <input matInput name="qta" formControlName="qta" class="table-input">
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="tot">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Totale </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index"  [formGroupName]="index" class="base-table">
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill"  id="price-input">
                <input matInput name="tot" formControlName="tot" class="table-input">
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="percmargine">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Margine(%) </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index"  [formGroupName]="index" class="base-table">
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill"  id="price-input">
                <input matInput name="percmargine" formControlName="percmargine" class="table-input">
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="vendita">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Vendita </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index"  [formGroupName]="index" class="base-table">
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill" id="price-input">
                <input matInput name="vendita" formControlName="vendita" class="table-input">
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

        </mat-table>
        <button type="button" class="add-row-btn" (click)="addRow()">Aggiungi riga</button>
        <button type="button" class="add-row-btn" (click)="submitData()">Invia</button>
      </div>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export interface ArtElement {
  descrizione: string;
  codarticolo: string;
  costo: number;
  qta: number;
  tot: number;
  percmargine: number;
  vendita: number;
}

export interface InfoProdotti{
  prod_categoria: string;
  prod_codice: string;
  prod_costo: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crea-preventivo',
  templateUrl: './crea-preventivo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crea-preventivo.component.css']
})

export class CreaPreventivoComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient){}

  tempcategoryproduct : string[] = []
  codartFilter = new FormControl("")
  descFilter = new FormControl("")
  prodotti : InfoProdotti[]         //array che collega categoria/articolo/prezzo
  categoryproduct : string[] = []   //contiene tutte le categorie di prodotti
  data: ArtElement[] = [ { descrizione: '', codarticolo:'',costo:0,qta:0,tot:0,percmargine:0,vendita:0 },
  { descrizione: '', codarticolo:'',costo:0,qta:0,tot:0,percmargine:0,vendita:0 },
  { descrizione: '', codarticolo:'',costo:0,qta:0,tot:0,percmargine:0,vendita:0 } ];
      dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<AbstractControl[]>([]);
      rows: FormArray = this.fb.array([]);
      form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({'data' : this.rows});

  displayedColumns = [
    'descrizione',
    'codarticolo',
    'costo',
    'qta',
    'tot',
    'percmargine',
    'vendita',
  ]

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data.forEach((d: ArtElement) => this.addRow(d, false));
        this.updateView();
this.categoryproduct.push('test','test1','test2','test3')
    this.descFilter.valueChanges
    .subscribe(
      value => {
        if(!value)  this.tempcategoryproduct = this.categoryproduct
        else this.tempcategoryproduct = this.categoryproduct.filter(item => (item + "") === value || item?.toLowerCase().indexOf(value!.toLowerCase()) >=0 )
      }
    )
  }

  emptyTable() {
    while (this.rows.length !== 0) {
      this.rows.removeAt(0);
    }
  }

  addRow(d?: ArtElement, noUpdate?: boolean) {
    const row = this.fb.group({
      'descrizione'   : '',
      'codarticolo'     : '',
      'costo'     : null,
      'qta'     : null,
      'tot'     : null,
      'percmargine'     : null,
      'vendita'     : null,
    });
    console.log(this.descFilter.value)
    this.rows.push(row);
    if (!noUpdate) { this.updateView(); }
  }

  updateView() {
    this.dataSource.next(this.rows.controls);
  }

  submitData(){
    console.log(this.rows)
  }

  resetDescriptionFilter(){
    this.tempcategoryproduct = this.categoryproduct
  }

  setDescValue(row: number, value: string){
    this.rows.value[row].descrizione = value

    console.log(this.rows.value)
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to create something like this?